# ListlinePlot 3D How to make color bar match the z value

Tags: plotting, legending

The code is like this:

```
a1 = {0.1212, 0.1713, 0.2011, 0.1234, 0.037, 0.023, 0.0198, 0.0174, 
   0.0151, 0.0134, 0.0123, 0.0112, 0.0098, 0.0091, 0.0085, 0.0078, 
   0.0072, 0.0066, 0.0063, 0.0058, 0.0053};
a2 = {0.1202, 0.1371, 0.1219, 0.1904, 0.2093, 0.2833, 0.1941, 0.5119, 
   0.0843, 0.0122, 0.0103, 0.0093, 0.0081, 0.0072, 0.0065, 0.0055, 
   0.0049, 0.0043, -0.018, 0.0032, 0.0029};
a3 = {0.114, 0.138, 0.1313, 0.124, 0.304, 0.317, 0.34, 0.0143, 0.0119,
    0.00988, 0.0083, 0.0069, 0.0058, -0.0602, 0.00988, 0.00666, 
   0.00404, 0.00363, 0.00205, 0.00415, -0.0168};
a4 = {0.08978, 0.1169, 0.1336, 0.1644, 0.3291, 0.4113, 0.1672, 0.0574,
    0.0607, -0.0077, -0.184, 0.0162, -0.03413, 0.02601, 
   0.009227, -0.0138, -0.00198, -0.033, -0.0373, 0.0089, 0.01734};
a5 = {0.116, 0.0896, 0.158, 0.132, 0.255, 0.382, 0.163, 0.125, 0.0667,
    0.0281, 0.0306, -0.103, -0.0105, -0.0176, 0.0246, 0.0503, 0.03, 
   0.000698, 0.00419, 0.0121, 0.004};
a = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};
ListPointPlot3D[a, DataRange -> {{20, 220}, {30, 110}}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-0.4, 0.6}}], Below], 
 PlotTheme -> "Business", PlotStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[0.01]]}]
```

[image]

I can change the value in the  `BarLegend`, but it has no effect on the color in the 3D plot. I want to make the value of color in the plot match with the value of color shown in the BarLegend. I have searched a lot, but I still cannot find the solution. It might be very easy. Sorry for my ingnorance.
Thank you

Comment: do you get what you need with `ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-0.4, 0.6}}]@#3 &)`?

Comment: also add `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` if needed.

Comment: @Kglr, Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried it. It seems that the color changes, but I don't know if the values of color match the set of bar ```PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-0.4, 0.6}}], Below]```. What's the relation between the the set of {-0.4,0.6} in two places.